# Weird behavior when changing orientation

Tags: iphone, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a view with a pan gesture. I programmed its behavior perfectly on portrait mode, but when I change it to landscape mode its acting differently. The translation x,y are the same as in portrait mode which is what i would expect. But in many places it seems as the x and y are flipped.

Also, the width and height of the view stays the same. This is weird cause i would figure that the width should have a bigger value than the height right now. It doesn't.

I would love to give a piece of code but it looks like a general issue more than a specific bad line somewhere.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Thanks

Comment: could me sent any sceenshot?

Comment: a screenshot would not help cause the view takes the all window.

Comment: in such cases I create a test project from scratch. In most cases it helps to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe seems like normal behaviour if you implemented the handling of the pan-gesture yourself and don't account for the orientation change in it.

The width and height of your views will stay the same if you don't have appropriate resizing masks set (or resize them in code when `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` is called).
Also, the frame of the application window (`[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]`) won't change after a rotation event.

Is this what you are seeing?